# 3D Polygons from list

Tags: arcpy, polygon, 3d-analyst, arcscene

So I have a list like this:

```
list = [[[-3, -2, 2], [3, -2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, 2]], [[3, -2, -2], [-3, -2, -2], [-3, 2, -2], [3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, 2], [-3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, -2], [-3, -2, -2]], [[-3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, -2], [-3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, -2], [3, -2, -2], [3, -2, 2], [-3, -2, 2]]]
```

Now I want to create a 3D Shapefile with Z-Values out of it. I tried several approaches. The one that works best is this:

```
import arcpy    
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Enabled"


features =[]

for feature in list:
    # Create a Polygon object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Polygon objects
    features.append(
        arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(coordPair[0], coordPair[1], coordPair[2], coordPair[2]) for coordPair in feature])))


# Persist a copy of the Polyline objects using CopyFeatures
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "C:/Users/test_shape.shp")
```

What I get are flat Polygons which don't show Z order M Values in ArcScene. But at least they show up in 2D.

I already tried this one:

```
arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(coordPair[0], coordPair[1], coordPair[2], coordPair[2]) for coordPair in feature]), None, True, True))
```

But then no polygon shows up.

Comment: You say "no polygon shows up" - where does it not show up?

Comment: In ArcScene. I have rows in the Attribute Table but nothing visual and no X oder Y coords in feature property window.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help file on creating a [Polygon class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm) using `arcpy` it states the constructor syntax is **Polygon (inputs, {spatial_reference}, {has_z}, {has_m})**.

Your code does not explicitly state that you are creating a polygon with Z and M values, even though you set the environment setting. As the Copy Feature tool [honors Z and M settings](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm#GUID-235790F5-C37F-41F2-9A95-567AF7080C7E) one would have thought it would have added them but it did not.

I took the opportunity to expanded out your list comprehension as I find that code almost unreadable and what I provide below is much more readable to others. Also as a side note you don't set the spatial reference of your data, trust me that will come back and bite you, so strongly suggest you set that!

So your code needs to be as follows:

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Enabled"
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Enabled"

features =[]
list = [[[-3, -2, 2], [3, -2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, 2]], [[3, -2, -2], [-3, -2, -2], [-3, 2, -2], [3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, 2], [-3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, -2], [-3, -2, -2]], [[-3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, -2], [-3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, -2], [3, -2, -2], [3, -2, 2], [-3, -2, 2]]]

for feature in list:
    # Create a Polygon object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Polygon objects
    array = arcpy.Array()
    for coordPair in feature:
        point = arcpy.Point()
        point.X = coordPair[0]
        point.Y = coordPair[1]
        point.Z = coordPair[2]
        point.M = coordPair[2]
        array.append(point)
    features.append(arcpy.Polygon(array,None,True,True))

# Persist a copy of the Polygon objects using CopyFeatures
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "C:/scratch/test_shape.shp")
```

Et voila!

[image: ArcScene]

Comment: Thanks. I tried exactly your code. He creates the rows in the Shapefile but i dont see anything in Arcmap or ArcScene. Maybe i should try it on another computer or something like that. I have no idea why it wont show up.

Comment: When i not use ,None,True,True your code correctly creates those two polygons without Z-Value. When i add this he wont. :(

Comment: Not sure what I can say that can help. If I run the code as-is it works without error and the data can be displayed in 3D in ArcScene...

Answer (score 0):

What if you start by creating the shapefile and specify that it should have Z?

You can then use the InsertCursor to insert the polygons:

```
import arcpy,os
folder=r'C:\Test'
name='ZShape.shp'

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=folder, out_name=name, geometry_type='POLYGON', has_m='DISABLED', has_z='ENABLED', 
                                    spatial_reference="3006")

list = [[[-3, -2, 2], [3, -2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, 2]], [[3, -2, -2], [-3, -2, -2], [-3, 2, -2], [3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, 2], [-3, 2, 2], [-3, 2, -2], [-3, -2, -2]], [[-3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, -2], [-3, 2, -2]], [[-3, -2, -2], [3, -2, -2], [3, -2, 2], [-3, -2, 2]]]

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(folder,name),['SHAPE@'])

for feature in list:
    polygon=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature]))
    cursor.insertRow([polygon])
del cursor
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I dont have da in my arcpy module on this computer. What do i need to change to use the old InsertCursor?

Comment: Either way if i use InsertCursor like in your approach or i add "has_z value" when creating the Shapefile it wont generate any rows in the ShapeFile. :( i used exactly your code except of the data access module.

Comment: I dont know how the old cursors work so i cant help you